# Singular points of $k[[t]][x,y]/(y^2 = t(x^3+t^3)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field. Consider the affine scheme
$$X := \text{Spec }k[[t]][x,y]/(y^2 - t(x^3+t^3))$$
(Or more generally, we can replace $k[[t]]$ with any discrete valuation ring $R$ with uniformizer $t$)

This is a normal scheme, whose generic fiber an elliptic curve, and special fiber an affine line of multiplicity 2. At first, one might think that every point on the special fiber is not regular (in $X$), but this turns out to be false, since if $a\in k^\times$, then $(x-a,y,t)^2$ contains $t^2$, and $y^2 = tx^3+t^4$, hence $tx^3$. But it also contains $tx-ta$, hence contains $tx^3-atx^2$ and $tx^2-atx$, and thus contains $tx^2$, and hence $tx$, and hence $t$. Thus, the cotangent space at $(x-a,y,t)$ is actually of dimension 2, generated by $x-a$ and $y$, so $(x,y,t)$ is the unique singular point on $X$.

This example appears in Qing Liu's book (Example 8.3.54), where the uniqueness of that singular point is asserted. However, I would never have thought that $(x,y,t)$ was the only singular point on $X$. It seemed natural to me that every point on the special fiber should be singular on $X$.

My question is: How do I fix my (bad) intuition? How can I adjust my intuition to see/guess that $(x,y,t)$ is the unique singular point of $X$ without having to go through the computations? Is there a way to explain the uniqueness of the singular point without explicitly computing the (co)tangent space as above?

Comment: Just a comment, but if you look at $k[[t]][x]/(x^2-t)$. Then this is the local ring at the point $(0,0)$ of the parabola $x^2-t=0$. This is a smooth point since the parabola is smooth. But looking at $t=0$, you get $k[x]/(x^2)$ which is of multiplicity 2. This just mean that the projection $(x,t)\mapsto t$ ramifies at $(0,0)$. Your example is a higher dimensional analog. The singularities of the special fiber are related to the map $X\rightarrow\operatorname{Spec}k[[t]]$. There are often much more of them than singularities in $X$.